# How do I make the DEBUG variable in my settings.py available in my templates in Django?

Tags: python, django

Without having to go through the dictionary in render_to_response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has this built into the `django.core.context_processors.debug` context processor.  So you just need to add that to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting in your `settings.py`. This adds the `debug` context variable to all views using request context, and the source looks like this:

```
def debug(request):
    "Returns context variables helpful for debugging."
    context_extras = {}
    if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
        context_extras['debug'] = True
        from django.db import connection
        context_extras['sql_queries'] = connection.queries
    return context_extras
```